# How do I merge hundreds of columns in a CSV file with python

Tags: python, json, csv

Say I have a CSV file with many hundreds of columns (comma separated):

```
ID,Column1,Column2,...,Column700
1,data,,...,
2,,data,...,
...
700,,,...,data
```

How do I merge the columns so that I have all the "data" in one column?
The CSV file was created from a JSON file from here: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED

Here is the code I am using (from another SO post) to convert to CSV from JSON:

```
def to_string(s):
    try:
        return str(s)
    except:
        #Change the encoding type if needed
        return s.encode('utf-8')

def reduce_item(key, value):
    global reduced_item

    #Reduction Condition 1
    if type(value) is list:
        i=0
        for sub_item in value:
            reduce_item(key+'_'+to_string(i), sub_item)
            i=i+1

    #Reduction Condition 2
    elif type(value) is dict:
        sub_keys = value.keys()
        for sub_key in sub_keys:
            reduce_item(key+'_'+to_string(sub_key), value[sub_key])

    #Base Condition
    else:
        reduced_item[to_string(key)] = to_string(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 4: #original was !=
        print ("\nUsage: python json_to_csv.py <node_name> <json_in_file_path> <csv_out_file_path>\n")
        #print ("Trying this without command line arguments")
    else:
    #Reading arguments
        #node = sys.argv[1]
        #json_file_path = sys.argv[2]
        #csv_file_path = sys.argv[3]

        node = "CVE_Items"
        json_file_path = "some\file.json"
        csv_file_path = "some\file.csv"

        fp = open(json_file_path, 'r')
        json_value = fp.read()
        raw_data = json.loads(json_value)

        try:
            data_to_be_processed = raw_data[node]
        except:
            data_to_be_processed = raw_data

        processed_data = []
        header = []
        for item in data_to_be_processed:
            reduced_item = {}
            reduce_item(node, item)

            header += reduced_item.keys()

            processed_data.append(reduced_item)

        header = list(set(header))
        header.sort()

        with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in processed_data:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

And here is one sample entry from the JSON file:

```
{
  "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
  "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "6208",
  "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2017-08-14T18:06Z",
  "CVE_Items" : [ {
    "cve" : {
      "CVE_data_meta" : {
        "ID" : "CVE-2003-1547"
      },
      "affects" : {
        "vendor" : {
          "vendor_data" : [ {
            "vendor_name" : "francisco_burzi",
            "product" : {
              "product_data" : [ {
                "product_name" : "php-nuke",
                "version" : {
                  "version_data" : [ {
                    "version_value" : "6.5"
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5_beta1"
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5_rc3"
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5_rc2"
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5_rc1"
                  } ]
                }
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      },
      "problemtype" : {
        "problemtype_data" : [ {
          "description" : [ {
            "lang" : "en",
            "value" : "CWE-79"
          } ]
        } ]
      },
      "references" : {
        "reference_data" : [ {
          "url" : "http://secunia.com/advisories/8478"
        }, {
          "url" : "http://securityreason.com/securityalert/3718"
        }, {
          "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/316925/30/25250/threaded"
        }, {
          "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/317230/30/25220/threaded"
        }, {
          "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/7248"
        }, {
          "url" : "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/11675"
        } ]
      },
      "description" : {
        "description_data" : [ {
          "lang" : "en",
          "value" : "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in block-Forums.php in the Splatt Forum module for PHP-Nuke 6.x allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via the subject parameter."
        } ]
      }
    },
    "configurations" : {
      "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
      "nodes" : [ {
        "operator" : "OR",
        "cpe" : [ {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5",
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_beta1",
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_beta1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc1",
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc2",
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc3",
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        } ]
      } ]
    },
    "impact" : {
      "baseMetricV2" : {
        "cvssV2" : {
          "vectorString" : "(AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:P/A:N)",
          "accessVector" : "NETWORK",
          "accessComplexity" : "MEDIUM",
          "authentication" : "NONE",
          "confidentialityImpact" : "NONE",
          "integrityImpact" : "PARTIAL",
          "availabilityImpact" : "NONE",
          "baseScore" : 4.3
        },
        "severity" : "MEDIUM",
        "exploitabilityScore" : 8.6,
        "impactScore" : 2.9,
        "obtainAllPrivilege" : false,
        "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
        "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
        "userInteractionRequired" : true
      }
    },
    "publishedDate" : "2003-12-31T05:00Z",
    "lastModifiedDate" : "2017-08-08T01:29Z"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Will help if you put a simple input and output example, omitting the 700 column fact in the example of course ;)

Comment: Do you have any Python code where you have already started on the solution?  Why convert JSON into a CSV, you can take the JSON data directly as an object in PHP and dump it to CSV format in just a few lines, btw.  You can probably do the same in Python.

Comment: @Aron - Added samples as requested. I don't have the option of using PHP at this time.

Comment: It kinda sounds like a "write my code" question since you aren't telling us what the problem with your existing code is. Can you specify it so we don't have to go looking (even if it might be quite obvious, it's nice to know what we're looking for, it makes pulling out a solution much quicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a CSV file with many, many columns, but each record only has the ID and one (non-ID) column populated, and the no two records have the same (non-ID) column populated.  So essentially you want to "fold" all 700 records into just one.

Since the ID values are all different, I'm not sure how you want to merge them into one record.  I'll assume you know what to do in this case, so I won't bother trying to get that part right.

Assuming your data is in a file called `nist.csv`, you can read in the records into a `merged_record` like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('nist.csv'))

# Extract the header:
header = next(reader)

# Initialize an empty merged_record:
merged_record = [''] * len(header)

# Populate the merged_record with data from the CSV file:
for record in reader:
    for i,value in enumerate(record):
        if value:  # only overwrite if the value is non-empty
            merged_record[i] = value
```

Once you have the `header` and `merged_record`, you can output them into a new CSV file named `nist_merged.csv` like this:

```
with open('nist_merged.csv', 'w') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(merged_record)
```

You can reduce this to just one line like this:

```
csv.writer(open('nist_merged.csv', 'w')).writerows([header, merged_record])
```

Again, the ID field may not be what you want, but since there are only two lines in this new CSV file, it should be easy enough for you to change it to whatever you want it to be.